# How can I use a created volume in my container using docker compose?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

In docker 1.9 I can create volumes and I can use it on my container as the exemple:

```
$ docker volume create --name testing-volume
$ docker run -it -v testing-volume:/var/lib/mysql busybox sh -c 'ls -alh/var/lib/'
```

It will show the mysql folder on the output as expected.

But how can I use a volume using docker-compose?

I saw that ther is a volume_driver directive but it is not working, my last try was like this

docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
   image: percona
   ports:
       "3306:3306"
   environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
   volume_driver: testing-volume
   volumes:
       "/var/lib/mysql"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql:
    image: percona
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
    volume_driver: local
    volumes:
        - "testing-volume:/var/lib/mysql"
```

If you are using any custom driver you can change on *volume_driver* directive.